# Preserving file creation date while uploading file

Tags: asp.net

We have an aspx-page in which files are uploaded to a server. What is important here is that the files **preserves** the filecreationtime.

What I'm doing after the file is uploaded to the server is trying to get the file creationtime from the source file (via FileInfo.CreationTimeUtc or File.GetCreationTimeUtc) so that I can update the target file.

The program is throwing an "Unauthorized Access Error" (on my development machine in debug mode, client and server is the same virtual machine) and on the production machine it is returning "1-1-1601 0:00:00".

How can I solve this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem. As a workaround, I use a javascript function tied to the onClientClick event (fires before the onClick) of the button excuting the upload. The FileUpload component has a property [files] an object array holding the selected file(s). An object has a property lastModifiedDate. This value I store in a hiddenfield. In the onClick method I retrieve that value.